# How can I attach a rotary encoder to a retractable dog lead?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, prototyping

I need to know how I can attach a rotary encoder to something string/wire that I can pull and it retracts automatically

My idea was to take apart a retractable dog lead leash and affix it to it somehow, but I'm not seeing how I could make that work.

I've included a picture of the dog leash(right) and the rotary endoer(left).

The only goal here is to measure distance/velocity of a retractable string/wire. I'm not tied down to using a dog leash or rotary encoder, open to any suggestions.

Is there any other solutions that are not very expensive?

[image]

Comment: tried superglue?

Comment: Seems more like a mechanical engineering problem :p You could try some 2 part epoxy, build up a little base... Maybe

Comment: You want to make your own string encoder? You can probably find a professional one for < $200. If you insist, I'd be tempted to remake a bunch of parts and reuse mostly just the spring and cord.. but I have a couple lathes sitting there waiting to be fired up.

Comment: I'm not sure if gluing, even if it did hold, would work for this. I'm not even sure if the dog leash is a good solution. I need to pull a string, and have that knob on the rotary encoder spin with it. How that is done, I'm at a loss

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I'm not following what you're suggesting. Do you have any reference materials on how to make a string encoder?

Comment: @JamesWierzba Nope, but I think it might be easier to turn new parts out of aluminum (give it a shaft and maybe use a flex shaft coupler which is tolerant of the inevitable misalignment) than to reliably join things to molded plastic. Google images 'string pot' or 'string encoder' for ideas.

Comment: [Here](http://www.andymark.com/product-p/am-2674.htm) is a 3D printed solution for a 10-turn pot. You can save money by making your own parts and using your own pot or encoder.

Comment: Use a BLDC motor and three phase rectifier, and maybe you can get that dog to recharge your phone.

Comment: Instead of a mechanical encoder that connects with a shaft, have you considered building an [optical encoder](http://heliosoph.mit-links.info/make-your-own-rotary-encoder/)

Comment: I had not thought of that, good idea. I will do some investigating on that. I wish I could upvote, feel free to post an answer of the suggestion

Comment: Beware that when you compute the "position" of the string that you will need to account for the spiral winding of the string. Also if power hits are an issue (if you are computing string position), you won't know where you are in the string. Not sure if it matters or not to you, but I've run into that in the past.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of a shaft driven rotary encoder, you might be able to build an [optical encoder](http://heliosoph.mit-links.info/make-your-own-rotary-encoder/) that uses optical sensors to read a pattern printed on a disk.

A simple encoder uses white/black alternating sectors so it can only tell you the speed of the disk, not the direction or position:

[image]

*Image credit: [heliosoph - Make your own rotary encoder](http://heliosoph.mit-links.info/make-your-own-rotary-encoder/)*

More complex sensors can use multiple optical sensors and use encoding stripes on the disk so it can determine position and direction. There are [multiple ways to do the encoding.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_encoder#Ways_of_encoding_shaft_position)

Here's simple binary encoding:

[image: Binary encoded disk]

*Image credit: [Cburnett - Image:Encoder Disc (3-Bit).svg, CC BY-SA 3.0](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=1429319)*

But this has the drawback that if the disk stops between sectors, the bit pattern is ambiguous.

By using [Gray Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_encoder#Gray_encoding), any two adjacent codes differ by only one bit position, which eliminates that ambiguity:

[image: Gray Encoded disk]

*Image credit: [jjbeard - Replacement for Image:Encoder-disc.png, Public Domain](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=801435)*

Comment: Do optical encoders come prebuilt from any suppliers or would I have to make one myself?

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

*Figure 1. This illustration clearly demonstrates the problem of making mechanical sketches with a schematic editor.*

- Mount the dog-lead on a base board with a sturdy capstan and connect the encoder to the capstan with a flexible link.
- Wrap the dog-lead one or more turns around the capstan to give a good grip.
- Make a stop so that the rewinding stops before the wire end runs off the capstan.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to attach a retractable string to a knob, then go kick that old broken lawnmower/generator/weedeater/whatever in your garage one last time (just for the gratification of it).

Now take out a screwdriver/saw and cut off the pull-start mechanism.

Inside, you have a spool of string, a retracting spring (which you ***DO NOT*** want to have "pop out," as it takes many minutes & a few nicks/cuts to rewind & re-seat), and 1-2 "little levers" mounted so they "stick out" into the center when the string is pulled, latching onto ths shaft of the (now removed) motor that the pull-starter *used* to start.

Now just make sure to put a cap on your rotary encoder that the "little levers" can engage, then slap her together & start tugging ;)

(P.S. This question actually *would be* a bit more on-topic on http://engineering.stackexchange.com )

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the degree of accuracy you want it may be acceptable to pinch the cord between two rubber wheels and fix the encoder to one of the axles.  A bit like the [wire feed on a MIG welder](http://www.mig-welding.co.uk/wire-feed.htm).